# How to Grant 'ALTER USER' privileges to AWS redshift user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

not able to grant 'ALTER USER' privileges to one of exsisting user in redshift cluster.

I have tried below statement but got error

`GRANT ALTER USER TO or_user;`

ERROR: Grant/Revoke system privilege on User is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRANT permission only work for table, database, schema, function, procedure, language, or column.

You can try to do something like:

```
CREATE ROLE testrole;

GRANT ROLE testrole TO test1;

GRANT ALTER USER TO ROLE testrole;
```

I did this test:

```
CREATE USER test1 WITH PASSWORD 'Test1password';
CREATE USER test2 WITH PASSWORD 'Test2password';

CREATE ROLE testrole;

GRANT ROLE testrole TO test1;

GRANT ALTER USER TO ROLE testrole;
```

Than i connected with the test1 user and run:

```
ALTER USER test2 password 'Test5password';
```

Comment: You can GRANT CREATE USER to a role in redshift, you can try to do the same with ALTER USER. Create a role give the role permission to the user and than try to do the GRANTE ALTER USER to that role.

Comment: Above commands throughing syntax error on at near 'ON', also tried creating role and assinging ALTER USER to it. 

`GRANT ALTER USER TO my_role;`

`ERROR: Grant/Revoke system privilege on User is not supported.`

Comment: CREATE ROLE some_role;

GRANT ALTER USER TO ROLE some_role;

GRANT ROLE some_role to or_user;  this correct syntax, but stilll error permission denied

Comment: Thanks to the reply, i tried to do the same thing the aws doc recomended but is also with sintax error. I'll keep trying, anything new i let you know.

Comment: The only solution i found was this one: I have updated the solution posted, could you try?

Comment: creating roles and assigning them to users, works. we can check the SVV_SYSTEM_PRIVILEGES table.
but didn't solve my ultimate question below.

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75281987/aws-redshift-user-password-change-permission-denied